# Extra padding in CSS-based navigation

Tags: html, css

I'm having some issues with CSS based navigation I came up with. For some reason there's a small amount of padding (3px or so) between each navigation item, just to the right of the vertical line. Also, in firefox the white :hover is offset slightly making it looked more like tabbed navigation when you mouse over it. Here's the jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/9m24tf4a/7/

On a side note, is there a simple way to have the vertical lines take up 90% of the height instead?

HTML:

```
<div id="header_nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="first">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#header_nav {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
clear: both;
height: 36px;
background-color: #ccc;
border-top: 1px solid #b6b2a9;
border-bottom: 1px solid #b6b2a9;
}
#header_nav ul {
width: 1000px;
padding: 0px;
line-height: 36px;
margin: 0px 100px 0px 100px;
}
#header_nav ul li {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline-block;
font: 14px/36px 'Arial', sans-serif;
color: #555559;
height: 36px;
line-height: 36px;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
width: auto;
border-right: 1px solid #b6b2a9;
}
#header_nav ul li:hover {
background-color: #fff;
width: auto;
}
#header_nav ul li a {
font: 14px/36px 'Arial', sans-serif;
color: #555559;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 36px;
margin: 0 17px;
padding: 0px;
}
#header_nav ul li.first {
/* border-left: 1px solid #b6b2a9; */
/* margin-left: 0px; */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a known padding generated by LI elements displayed inline. You either work with float: left, either set font-size: 0 to the UL element, then come back and set it back to your desired font-size to the LI element itself.

Here's the snippet with font-size: 0; to the UL element.

```css
#header_nav {
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
clear: both;
height: 36px;
background-color: #ccc;
border-top: 1px solid #b6b2a9;
border-bottom: 1px solid #b6b2a9;
}
#header_nav ul {
width: 1000px;
padding: 0px;
line-height: 36px;
margin: 0px 100px 0px 100px;
  font-size: 0;
}
#header_nav ul li {
list-style-type: none;
display: inline-block;
font: 14px/36px 'Arial', sans-serif;
color: #555559;
height: 36px;
line-height: 36px;
padding: 0px;
margin: 0px;
width: auto;
border-right: 1px solid #b6b2a9;
  font-size: 16px;
}
#header_nav ul li:hover {
background-color: #fff;
width: auto;
}
#header_nav ul li a {
font: 14px/36px 'Arial', sans-serif;
color: #555559;
text-decoration: none;
line-height: 36px;
margin: 0 17px;
padding: 0px;
}
#header_nav ul li.first {
/* border-left: 1px solid #b6b2a9; */
/* margin-left: 0px; */
}
```

```html
 <div id="header_nav">
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#" class="first">Home</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link 4</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link 5</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Link 6</a></li>
  </ul>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use "`float: left`" instead of "`display: inline-block`" if you are comfortable with it:

```
#header_nav ul li {
    ...
    float: left;
    ...
}
```